# How can I set up sockets to do either "send/receive" or "receive/send"

Tags: c, sockets

How can I setup my sockets routine to either "send" (first) or (switch) to "receive" if data is "sent" from another computer (first)?

thanks

general code:

```
-(void) TcpClient{
    char buffer[128];
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    struct hostent *host;
    int s;

    host = gethostbyname("10.0.0.3");

    memcpy(&(sin.sin_addr), host->h_addr,host->h_length);
    sin.sin_family = host->h_addrtype;
    sin.sin_port = htons(4000);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));

    while(1){//this is the Client sequence:
        send(s, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);//but what if the Server sends first ?? Client needs to receive here first
        recv(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    }
    close(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A socket is bi-directional.  It can be read from and written to at any time.  If you want to write a single routine that decides when to read and when to write, you need to use the `select()` function.  It will tell you when a socket has data available for reading, and when the socket can accept data for sending.  If the socket receives data before you have data to send, your routine can detect that and perform a "receive/send" operation.  If you have data to send before the socket receives data, your routine can detect that and perform a "send/receive" operation instead.  For example:

```
while (1)
{
    fd_set fd;
    FD_ZERO(&fd);
    FD_SET(s, &fd);

    timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    int ret;

    if (select(s+1, &fd, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0)
    {
        ret = recv(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0); 
        if (ret > 0)
            send(s, buffer, ret, 0);
    } 
    else
    {
        ret = send(s, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
        if (ret > 0)
            recv(s, buffer, ret, 0); 
    }
}
```

Comment: does unblocking need to be set?

Comment: No, `select()` works with both blocking and non-blocking sockets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `select()` system call to deal with multiple sockets and to trigger actions when data is available for reading or writing.  The internet is full of information about socket programming in general, maybe start [here](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html), which includes some links to other good information.

Also [this one](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#select).

And just about any book on network programming should have some good examples, too.